# Laravel Repository Issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, repository-pattern

I'm having the weird experience working with Laravel 4. Not wasting too much of time I'll dive into the issue. Okay, I'm organizing namespaces into directory so, I might have missed or something but plz do check it out. I am in need to help. Okay, let me show you the codes.

```
  File: app/services/profile/profile.php


   <?php namespace Services\Profile;

     use Services\Repo\ProfileRepoInterface as ProfileInterface;

     class Profile
     {
        protected $profile;
        function __construct(ProfileInterface $profile)
        {
            $this->profile = $profile;
        }
     }


File: app/services/repo/ProfileRepoInterface.php
<?php 
namespace Services\Repo;
interface ProfileRepoInterface{
    public function all();
}

>  File: app/services/repo/EloquentProfileRepository.php
>         <?php 
>      namespace Services\Repo; 
>     
>     class EloquentProfileRepository implements ProfileRepoInterface
>     {
>       public function all()
>       {
>           return 'Returned All';
>       }
>     }
```

I binded the Interface in the top of the routes.php file

```
File: routes.php

    App::bind('Services\Repo\ProfileRepoInterface','Services\Repo\EloquentProfileRepository');
Route::get('/posts',function()
{
        $pro = new Services\Profile\Profile;
        var_dump($pro);
});
```

I've tried adding "app/services" into the classmap of composer.json file but didn't work. Even tried adding to the global.php file in ClassLoader still doesn't work.
What I might have done wrong? I get the error.

> Argument 1 passed to Services\Profile\Profile::__construct() must be
>   an instance of Services\Repo\ProfileRepoInterface, none given, called
>   in E:\server\www\laravel\app\routes.php on line 20 and defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
use Services\Repo\ProfileRepoInterface as ProfileInterface;
```

Laravel will not auto inject it for you, it will expect you to manually pass it while instantiating your class. So you have just to bind it:

```
App::bind('ProfileInterface','Services\Repo\EloquentProfileRepository');
```

And it will magically inject it:

```
 <?php namespace Services\Profile;

 class Profile
 {
    protected $profile;

    function __construct(ProfileInterface $profile)
    {
        $this->profile = $profile;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Yeah @Antonio, got the ans. Just forgot to use that interface.